# Error Python AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy intentando hacer mi primera calculadora con interfaz gráfica con tkinter, y, he tenido el problema de arriba, el programa solo me da ese error, y he estado buscando posibles soluciones pero lo que he visto, no me ha solucionado el problema.

No sé si hay que poner todo el código, (he buscado como hacer las funciones en Internet, porque no sabia, pero no es ese el problema). El problema está en la línea 99 (en mi IDE esa es la línea), pero no se como resolverlo, creo que se relaciona con la línea 10 del código, porque es allí donde defino la variable que después uso, en la línea 99, agradecería que me dijerais como solucionarlo, porque, no tengo ni idea ahora mismo.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("calculadora")
window.configure(background="SkyBlue4")#

#para almacenar los cálculos numéricos, voy a crear una variable que va a estar vacia donde se almacenaran las operaciones a realizar, pero no ejecutará las operaciones, solo las almacenará

operador = ""
texto_pantalla = tk.StringVar()

window.rowconfigure([0,1,2,3,4,5], minsize = 50, weight = 1)
window.columnconfigure([0,1,2,3], minsize = 50, weight = 1)

#funciones de la calculadora

def clear():
  global operador
  operador = ""
  texto_pantalla.set("0")

def click(almacena_clicks):
  global operador
  operador += str(almacena_clicks)
  texto_pantalla.set(operador)

#para que no halla errores en la funcion resultado al introducir operaciones que no se pueden realizar, voy a poner un try/except

def resultado():
  global operador
  try:
    r = str(eval(operador))
  except:
    r = "Operación sin solución"
  texto_pantalla.set(r)

#la funcion columnspan, indica el numero de columnas que debe ocupar el boton, si en vez de un numero de  x columnas, se quisiera un numero de x filas, se hace con la función de rowspan. Para que los botones se ejecuten como vamos a llamar a la función click y en ella reside el parámetro almacena_clicks, hay que usar la funcion lambda, poner command = lambda:click(parámetro al que pertenece el botón)

button_0 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "0")
button_0.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2 ,sticky = "nsew")

button_coma = tk.Button(master = window, text = ",")
button_coma.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

button_igual = tk.Button(master = window, text = "=")
button_igual.grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = "nsew")

button_1 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "1")
button_1.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

button_2 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "2")
button_2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

button_3 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "3")
button_3.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

button_suma = tk.Button(master = window, text = "+")
button_suma.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = "nsew")

button_4 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "4")
button_4.grid( row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

button_5 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "5")
button_5.grid( row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

button_6 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "6")
button_6.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

button_resta =tk.Button(master = window, text = "-")
button_resta.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = "nsew")

button_7 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "7")
button_7.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

button_8 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "8")
button_8.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

button_9 = tk.Button(master = window, text = "9")
button_9.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

button_multiplicacion = tk.Button(master = window, text = "x")
button_multiplicacion.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = "nsew")

button_ac = tk.Button(master = window, text = "AC")
button_ac.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

button_parentesis_izquierdo = tk.Button(master = window, text = "(")
button_parentesis_izquierdo.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

button_parentesis_derecho = tk.Button(master = window, text = ")")
button_parentesis_derecho.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

button_division = tk.Button(master = window, text = "/")
button_division.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = "nsew")

#hacer la pantalla de la puuuuta calculadora. Para que halla separación entre la pantalla y los bordes, hacer un padx = un número y un pad y = un número

Pantalla = tk.Entry (window, font = ('arial', 20, 'bold'), width = 20, bd = 20,insertwidth = 10,background = "powder blue")
Pantalla = tk.Entry(texto_pantalla)
Pantalla.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la siguiente sentencia:

```
Pantalla = tk.Entry(texto_pantalla)
```

La variable `texto_pantalla` es un `StringVar` y la has utilizado como si fuese un `str`. Para obtener el *texto* de un `StringVar` tienes que utilizar su método `get`:

```
Pantalla = tk.Entry(texto_pantalla.get())
```

Sin embargo no es necesario utilizar un `StringVar` para manipular el texto de un `Entry`. Un `StringVar` se utiliza cuando quieres que un `Label` tenga *texto variable*. Por ejemplo:

```
texto_etiqueta = StringVar()
etiqueta = tk.Label(window, textvariable=texto_etiqueta)
```

**Para borrar el texto del *Entry* `Pantalla` y asignarle un nuevo valor utiliza sus métodos `delete` e `insert`:**

```
Pantalla.delete(0, tk.END)
Pantalla.insert(0, "123456")
```

Un saludo!