# Python: AttributeError: 'Opciones' has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

No se como explicar este problema. Es algo relacionado con este [problema pasado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412233/attributeerror-type-object-frame1-has-no-attribute-tk) que tuve, pero creo que mas con [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383816/error-python-attributeerror-stringvar-object-has-no-attribute-tk).

Tengo dos módulos: ayuda.py y funcayuda.py. En ayuda esta la interfaz que estoy haciendo que sostiene con una clase que se dedica a crear los frames y una función que los cambia cuando se llama.

```
class AppSimple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(PaginaGeneral)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
```

Esta es la pagina de inicio; funciona sin problemas aparentes:

```
class PaginaGeneral(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.imagen= tk.PhotoImage(file= "hola.gif")
        tituloPrograma= tk.Label(self, text= "PROGRAMA PRUEBA")
        tituloPrograma.pack()
        introduccionPrograma4= tk.Label(self, image= self.imagen).pack()

        botonSiguienteGeneral= tk.Button(self, text= "INICIO", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PaginaUno))
        botonSiguienteGeneral.pack()
```

El problema viene con la primera pagina:

```
class PaginaUno(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloGeneral= tk.Label(self, text= "SOY UN LABEL SUPREMO")
        tituloGeneral.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.imagenUno= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c1.png")
        self.imagenDos= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c2.png")
        self.imagenTres= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c3.png")
        self.imagenCuatro= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c4.png")
        self.imagenCinco= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c5.png")

        llamada= funcayuda.Opciones()
        botonUno= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenUno, command= llamada.Primera).grid(row=3, column=2)
        botonDos= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenDos, command= llamada.Segunda).grid(row=3, column=3)
        botonTres= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenTres, command= llamada.Tercera).grid(row=3, column=4)
        botonCuatro= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenCuatro, command= llamada.Cuarta).grid(row=4, column=2)
        botonCinco= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenCinco, command= llamada.Quinta).grid(row=4, column=4)
```

Hago una llamada al modulo funcayuda.py (específicamente a la clase Opciones) y lo guardo en la variable `llamada` y después a través de los `command` en los `tk.Button`  llamo a una función especifica de ese modulo.

```
#Este es el MODULO funcayuda.py

class Opciones():
    def Primera(self):
        self.opcionA= True
        self.Eleccion()
    def Segunda(self):
        self.opcionB= True
        self.Eleccion()
    def Tercera(self):
        self.opcionC= True
        self.Eleccion()
    def Cuarta(self):
        self.opcionD= True 
        self.Eleccion()
    def Quinta(self):
        self.opcionE= True
        self.Eleccion()
```

Y este a su vez hace una llamada a la función `Elección` que se encuentra dentro de la misma clase `Opciones` para que cambie al siguiente frame `PaginaDos`:

```
    def Eleccion(self):
        ayuda.AppSimple.switch_frame(self, ayuda.PaginaDos)
```

Pero no cambia, y no solo no cambia si no que arroja el error del titulo.

```
AttributeError: 'Opciones' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Esta es toda la ruta que sigue:

```
Proyecto>ayuda.py

>Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
>    return self.func(*args)
>
>  File "Proyecto\funcayuda.py", line 125, in Primera
>    self.Eleccion()
>
>  File "Proyecto\funcayuda.py", line 121, in Eleccion
>    ayuda.AppSimple.switch_frame(self, ayuda.PaginaDos)
>
>  File "Proyecto\ayuda.py", line 16, in switch_frame
>    new_frame = frame_class(self)
>
>  File "Proyecto\ayuda.py", line 54, in __init__
>    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
>
>  File "Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3121, in __init__
>    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
>
>  File "Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2563, in __init__
>    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
>
>  File "Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2532, in _setup
>    self.tk = master.tk
>
>AttributeError: 'Opciones' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Se que en esta comunidad suelen responder y ayudar favorablemente en los problemas de los usuarios dando respuestas que solucionan los problemas; quería pedirles en esta ocasión -si es posible- no se limitaran a ayudarme a solucionar mi problema, si no explicarme que es lo que estoy haciendo mal y  la teoría detrás de ello e igualmente referirme a la documentación especifica para poder aprender correctamente y que esta situación se repita lo menos posible en el futuro (lo menciono porque es la segunda vez que me ocurre [dicho en al principio, al referir a la primera ocasión en que se presento el problema] y no me gustaría un tercera).

---

## Actualizo:

Lo que hice fue meter un `lambda` al `command` pasándole las dos variables, esto aparentemente soluciono el problema; me gustaría saber otro método para obtener este mismo resultado pero sin tener que estar usando las funciones anónimas en cada botón.

```
class PaginaUno(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloGeneral= tk.Label(self, text= "SOY UN LABEL SUPREMO")
        tituloGeneral.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.imagenUno= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c1.png")
        self.imagenDos= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c2.png")
        self.imagenTres= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c3.png")
        self.imagenCuatro= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c4.png")
        self.imagenCinco= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes/ejemplo/c5.png")

        llamada= funcayuda.Opciones()
        botonUno= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenUno, command= lambda: [llamada.Primera, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]).grid(row=3, column=2)
        botonDos= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenDos, command= lambda: [llamada.Segunda, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]).grid(row=3, column=3)
        botonTres= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenTres, command= lambda: [llamada.Tercera, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]).grid(row=3, column=4)
        botonCuatro= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenCuatro, command= lambda: [llamada.Cuarta, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]).grid(row=4, column=2)
        botonCinco= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenCinco, command= lambda: [llamada.Quinta, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]).grid(row=4, column=4)
```

Algo a recalcar es otro problema que surgió a raíz de esta solución. En un momento de la ejecución del programa al presionar un determinado botón salta un `combobox` con diferentes opciones y al elegir una de ellas entonces pasa al siguiente `frame`, en este caso se salta ese proceso.

Es lógico, estoy llamando a `llamada.equis` e inmediatamente después a `switch.frame` por lo que no ejecuta debidamente la primera función, o al menos así lo entiendo.

```
class Opciones():
    def __init__(self):
        self.opcionSi= False
        self.opcionNo= False

    def eleccion(self):
        global variableVar

        if (self.opcionSi):
            def Elegido(*args):
                global variableVar
                comboElegido= combo.get()
                if combolegido== "1":
                    variableVar= False
                elif combolegido== "2":
                    variableVar= False
                elif combolegido== "3":
                    variableVar= False
                elif combolegido== "4":
                    variableVar= False
                elif combolegido== "5":
                    variableVar= False
                    
            combo= ttk.Combobox(self)
            combo['values'] =("Rojo", "Verde", "Amarillo", "Cyan", "Magenta") 
            combo.state(["readonly"])
            combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Elegido)
            combo.pack()

        elif (self.opcionNo):
            variableVar= True

    def Si(self):
        self.opcionSi= True
        self.eleccion()
    def RuidosNo(self):
        self.opcionNo= True
        self.eleccion()
```

Todo esto no aparece. Creo que metiéndolo directamente en ayuda.py podría resolver el problema pero me gustaría tener eso por separado.

Bueno, eso es todo. ¡Muchas gracias!

p.d. felices fiestas a todos.

Comment: Las clases no son contenedores de funciones. Estás invocando el método `AppSimple.switch_frame` directamente, pasándole como primer argumento `self` una instancia de la clase `Opciones`, en lugar de una instancia de `AppSimple`. Te recomiendo que mires cómo funciona el "protocolo descriptor".

Comment: Creo que Chema le ha dado justo. Realmente no entiendo qué haces con `new_frame = frame_class(self)`, y no hace sentido cuando usas su función en `ayuda.AppSimple.switch_frame(self, ayuda.PaginaDos)` (le pasas dos argumentos a una función que solo recibe uno)

Comment: @ChemaCortes ok, ok, leeré de ya lo de protocolo descriptor.
@ DannyTalent aaaah, ahí suponía que le debía pasar la clase self (propia de la funciona) y después el argumento que recibía mas adelante (el siguiente frame) 

Llevo poquísimo en el mundo de la programación, apenas dos meses creo y me fui directamente a escribir código, todos estos consejos sobre qué leer y demás me son de mucha ayuda. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es demasiado profundo para explicarlo aquí. Voy a intentar darte algunas ideas para guiarte en los próximos pasos.

Una función necesita de un entorno de ejecución que dé valores a los argumentos de entrada, cree las variables locales y resto de objetos que va a usar. Hablando con propiedad, cuando decimos que "definimos una función" lo que estamos realmente definiendo es un *"método"*. Una *"función ejecutable"* sería el método junto con el entorno listo para ser ejecutado. Cuando los entornos de ejecución son independientes entre sí estaríamos hablando de *"clausuras"*, pudiendo ejecutar varias funciones a la vez del mismo método sin que se interfirieran entre sí.

Por poner una *equivalencia*, si un "método" fuera una clase, una "función" sería una instancia inicializada de esa clase.

Cuando se define una clase, sus métodos, además del entorno de ejecución, necesitan saber a qué clase pertenecen y la instancia sobre la que actuar. El modo que tiene python de asociar a un método la información sobre la clase y la instancia está relacionado con el ["protocolo descriptor"](https://blog.ch3m4.org/2011/06/19/descriptores-parte-1/) del cuál dejo algunos artículos propios en los que [lo explicaba](https://blog.ch3m4.org/2011/06/19/descriptores-parte-1/). Normalmente, no es necesario conocer este protocolo, pero sí que es importante saber que es responsable del mecanismo de herencia de clases y que explica algunos de los problemas que estás teniendo.

Los botones del GUI necesitan como argumento un comando con el que ejecutar una acción cada vez que se pulsan. Este comando no es más que una función sin argumentos y sin valor de retorno.

Analizando tu código:

```py
    llamada= funcayuda.Opciones()
    botonUno= tk.Button(self,
                        image= self.imagenUno, 
                        command= llamada.Primera
              ).grid(row=3, column=2)
```

Creas una instancia de la clase `Opciones` con nombre `llamada` y pasas `llamada.Primera` como comando.

(Una anotación: intenta seguir el estilo pythónico de nombrar las variables, métodos y funciones con minúsculas (eg: `Opciones.primera`)).

Sin entrar en detalles del descriptor, cuando se invoca el método `llamada.Primera()` se busca el método `Primera` en la clase `Opciones` y se le pasa la instancia `llamada` como primer argumento (argumento `self`). Como no necesita más argumentos, ya está lista para ser usada como comando en un botón (eg: `cmd=llamada.Primera`).

Pero no valdría si necesitases pasar algún argumento. Entonces hay dos opciones:

- Usar una *expresión lambda* sin argumentos: `cmd=lambda : llamada.Primera(arg1, arg2)`
- Aplicación parcial de argumentos: `cmd=functools.partial(llamada.Primera, arg1, arg2)`

En la documentación verás la primera opción. Yo prefiero usar las segunda. En general, siempre que puedas evita las expresiones lambda (no se llevan bien con las *clausuras*).

Cuando pones:

```py
command= lambda: [llamada.Primera, self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)]
```

Al invocar esta función lambda, está creando una lista de dos items, siendo el segundo el resultado de ejecutar `self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)`. Es completamente equivalente a haber puesto simplemente:

```py
command= lambda: self.switch_frame(PaginaDos)
```

O, como a mi me gusta más:

```py
from functools import partial

command= partial(self.switch_frame, PaginaDos)
```

Para acabar, vayamos al error:

```py
class Opciones:
    def Primera(self):
        self.opcionA= True
        self.Eleccion()

    def Eleccion(self):
        ayuda.AppSimple.switch_frame(self, ayuda.PaginaDos)
```

> AttributeError: 'Opciones' object has no attribute 'tk'

Cuando accedes a `AppSimple.switch_frame` estás accediendo al método de la clase en crudo. Como primer argumento necesitas pasar una instancia de la clase `AppSimple` (eg: `isinstance(self, AppSimple) == True`), pero en realidad le estás pasando la instancia de la clase `Opciones`, que no deriva de `Tk`.

No sé realmente qué intentabas hacer, no veo coherencia entre instancias y código.

Intentaría crear algunos comandos para su uso en botones, algo así:

```py
myApp = AppSimple()
cmd_switch_general = partial(myApp.switch_frame, PaginaGeneral)
cmd_switch_page_one = partial(myApp.switch_frame, PaginaUno)
```

Tendrías que replantearte mejor el código, desacoplar más las llamadas entre módulos y evitar las variables globales. Usa [variables de control](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html), con *callback*, para desacoplar los cambios del interface gráfico del código que responde al cambio.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por pedazo de explicación! Justo he buscado lo de protocolo descriptor en google y me ha mandado a tu enlace (jaja). Disculpa por hacerte examinar tan a detalle un código excesivamente incoherente, como comentaba arriba, tengo poco aprendiendo y entre que conozco una cosa nueva y la aplico se va formando este monstruo de Frankenstein:)

Comment: Igual es mucho empezar con los _descriptores_. Ten paciencia y ves leyendo la documentación oficial, de donde podrás sacar bastantes ideas,